# OCaml - specify size of array in type

Tags: arrays, types, ocaml

Suppose I wanted to define an OCaml type of arrays of floats.  This could be done as
`type exampletype = Array of float`.  But suppose I wanted to limit this type to only include arrays of a fixed size.  Would it be possible to create such a type, or in this case, would it be more effective to use an appropriately sized tuple of floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OCaml array type doesn't include the size. If your arrays aren't too large you can, indeed, use tuples instead to have their sizes enforced at compile time.

It's possible to encode numbers in your OCaml types, and hence to enforce sizes at compile time. But personally I find the resulting structures to be far more trouble than they're worth. To do it nicely requires a language designed for the purpose. They're called "dependently typed" languages, so I hear. The idea is that their types can contain values (such as a specific number representing array size).

Comment: [This presentation](https://confengine.com/functional-conf-2019/proposal/13270/gadts-in-ocaml) shows a nifty way using GADTs to encode the length in the the type of a *list*. Not sure if it can be adapted to arrays.